# Items of Multiple ComboBoxes added to a ListBox

Tags: c#, combobox, visual-studio-2017, listbox, windows-forms-designer

I have 5 comboboxes listed and I will be selecting one item from each combobox and adding all to the listbox, I tried selecting one item from combobox1 and its get added to the listbox but when I select other item it also gets added to the list, so my question is how to restrict to only one selected item to the listbox from each Combobox?

Can you guys please help me

Comment: You need to share you code so that we can suggest what changes you need to make in it

Comment: You can add the Item selected from a ComboBox and the ComboBox reference to an intermediate List of class objects. Then verify whether the List already contains the reference of the ComboBox that generates a selection change event and add a new item to the ListBox only if the source ComboBox reference is not already stored.